# prove of $17^n-12^n-24^n+19^n \equiv 0 \pmod{35} $

Tags: number-theory

i came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755125/how-do-i-prove-that-17n-12n-24n19n-equiv-0-pmod35) and i saw the given solution but i can not understand how it proves the given problem. Ok i get that $lcm(5,7)= 35$ and it is the same as the $(mod 35)$. Please can someone help me?

Comment: Where are your problems exactly with the the solutions here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755125/how-do-i-prove-that-17n-12n-24n19n-equiv-0-pmod35 ?

Comment: Chinese rem theorem.

Comment: First of all i do not understant if this is the hole solution or just a small part?

Comment: @user147345 Welcome to Math.SE!  If you don't understand something in that solution, you should be asking your question as a comment there, rather than as a whole new question.

Comment: @Nicholas, I think a user with only 1 point can't leave comments.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson i could not leave a comment on that answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\ \{17,19\}\equiv \{12,24\}\ {\rm mod}\ 5,7\ $ and $\,f(x,y)=x^n\!+y^n$ is symmetric $\,f(x,y)=f(y,x)$

thus $\,f(17,19)\equiv f(12,24)\ {\rm mod}\ 5,7\,$ so $\,5,7\mid f(17,19)\!-\!f(12,24)\,\Rightarrow\,$ so too does $\,{\rm lcm}(5,7)=35$