# Show $\,1897\mid 2903^n - 803^n - 464^n + 261^n\,$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction

Show that: $2903^n - 803^n - 464^n + 261^n$ is divisible by $1897$ for all integers $n\geq1$ using induction.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: $1897 =7 \cdot 271$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755125/how-do-i-prove-that-17n-12n-24n19n-equiv-0-pmod35

Answer (score 5):

(I missed out the "by induction" in the question when I wrote this answer, but I will leave it here anyway. Do feel free to have it removed.)

I remember this as a classic Olympiad problem for factorization.

We can rewrite the given expression as:

$$(2903^n - 803^n) - (464^n - 261^n)$$

Then, factorizing (using the [difference of powers factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers)) we get:

$$(2903 - 803)(\dots) - (464 - 261)(\dots)$$
$$= 2100\cdot(\dots) - 203(\dots)$$

which is divisible by $7$. (I've omitted the expression in the bracket, but the important thing is that they are integers)

Next, we can also rewrite the given expression as:

$$(2903^n - 464^n) - (803^n - 261^n)$$

Factorizing, we get:

$$(2903 - 464)(\dots) - (803 - 261)(\dots)$$
$$=2439\cdot(\dots) - 542\cdot(\dots)$$

which is divisible by $271$ (because $271$ divides both $2439$ and $542$).

Since both $7$ and $271$ divides the given expression, it follows that $7\cdot271 = 1897$ must also divide it.

Comment: If we use congruence arithmetic *operations* (vs. divisibility *relations*) then the arithmetical essence (innate symmetry) becomes much clearer - as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ Exploit innate $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetry}$! $ $  Consider a simpler analogous example

$\qquad\phantom{\Rightarrow}\ \  \{ 52,\ \ \ \ 23\}\ \  \equiv\, \{2,\ \ \ 3\}\ \ \ \ {\rm mod}\,\ 10,7,\ \ $

$\qquad\Rightarrow\ \{52^n,\ \ 23^n\} \equiv \{2^n,\ \,3^n\}\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ 10,7,\ \ $ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825833/242)

$\qquad\Rightarrow\ \ \ 52^n\!+\! 23^n\ \ \equiv \ \ 2^n\!+3^n\ \ \,{\rm mod}\,\ 10,7,\ \ $ so also $\,{\rm mod}\ 70 = {\rm lcm}(10,7)\,$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242)

since addition $\,f(x,y)\, =\, x + y\ $ is $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetric}$  $\,f(x,y)= f(y,x),\ $  therefore its value depends only upon the (multi-)set $\,\{x,\,y\}.\ $ OP follows the same way:

$\qquad\!\phantom{\Rightarrow}  \{2903,\, 261\}\ \equiv\ \{803,\, 464\}\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ 271,7$

$\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \  2903^n\!+\!261^n\equiv\, 803^n\!+\!464^n\bmod 271\cdot 7\, [ = 1897]$

**Generally** $ $ if a polynomial $\,f\in\Bbb Z[x,y]\,$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetric}$ then as above

$\qquad\qquad\quad \{A, B\}\, \equiv\, \{a,b\}\ \ {\rm mod}\,\ m, n\,\ \Rightarrow\,\  f(A,B)\equiv f(a,b)\ \pmod{\!{\rm lcm}(m,n)}\qquad\quad$

a generalization of  [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) = constant-case optimization  of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem, plus a generalization of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825833/242) to (symmetric) bivariate polynomials.

Slightly more work yields a *much* more general result. Let $\,o_n(x) :=$ [order](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) of $\,x\pmod{\! n}$

[Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/787204/242) $\ $ If $\,\ \color{0a0}{m\mid a\!-\!c},\,\ \color{c00}{ n \mid a\!-\!d}\ $ and $\,b\,$ is coprime to $\ m,n,\,$  then

$\qquad\qquad\ \bbox[10px,border:1px solid #c00]{m,n\mid a^k\!+b^k\!-c^k\!-d^k\!\iff o_m\!\left(\frac{d}b\right)\!,\:\!o_{n}\!\left(\frac{c}b\right)\mid k}$

**Remark** $\, $ Induction (on $\:\!n)\:\!$ is in fact (implicitly) used in the above - it is simply hidden - being conveniently encapsulated for reuse in the linked proof of the Congruence Power Rule (or in the generalization, in the Polynomial Congruence Rule - proved by induction on the degree $\:\!n\:\!$ of the polynomial).

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$S_n = 2903^n - 803^n - 464^n + 261^n$$

$S_1 = 1897$ so the statement is true for $n=1$.

Assume true for n, and evaluate for (n+1):

$$S_{n+1} = 2903^{n+1} - 803^{n+1} - 464^{n+1} + 261^{n+1}= $$ 
$$=261\cdot S_n + 2642\cdot 2903^n - 542\cdot803^n - 203\cdot464^n$$

The first term divides by $1897$ by assumption. Let

$$T_n = 2642\cdot2903^n - 542\cdot803^n - 203\cdot464^n$$

If we can prove that $T_n$ divides by 1897 then we are done. Proceed by induction (again). $T_1 = 7140308 = 3764\cdot1897$, i.e. $T_1$ divides by 1897. Assume true for n and evaluate for (n+1).

$$T_{n+1} = 2642\cdot2903\cdot2903^n -542\cdot803\cdot803^n - 203\cdot464\cdot464^n =$$
$$=464\cdot T_n + (2903-464)\cdot2642\cdot2903^n - (803-464)\cdot542\cdot803^n$$

Again the  first term by assumption divides by 1897 and let
$$U_n = 6443838\cdot2903^n - 183738\cdot803^n$$

Now we just need to prove that $U_n$ divides by 1897. Proceed (yet again) by induction. $U_1 = 18558920100 = 9783300\cdot1897$. So $U_1$ divides by 1897. Assume true for n and evaluate for (n+1).

$$U_{n+1} = 6443838\cdot2903\cdot2903^n - 183738\cdot803\cdot803^n =$$
$$=803\cdot U_n +6443838\cdot(2903-803)\cdot2903^n$$

again the first term divides by 1897 (by assumption). The second term = $6443838\cdot2100\cdot2903^n = 13532059800\cdot 2903^n$ and $13532059800 = 7133400\cdot 1897$, so  $U_{n+1} $ divides by 1897.

(phew !! ).

Comment: This amounts to constructing a constant coeff order $4$ recurrence for $\,S_n,\,$ see the [explanation here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1253368/242)