# Prove that for any positive integer $n$, $2903^n-803^n-464^n+261^n$ is divisible by $1897$

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

$$\color{white}{\require{cancel}{.}}$$So I was again looking through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math equations that I thought that I might be able to solve when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/3TPMC4rLc7Y) video by [Cipher](https://www.youtube.com/@cipherunity). The question in the video in question was $$\text{Prove that for any positive integer }n\text{, }2903^n-803^n-464^n+261^n\text{ is divisible by }1897$$which I thought that I might be able to do.

### **Here is my attempt at proving the aforementioned statement**

---

#### **Restrictions that I am going to place down right away:**

---

1. We know that we are going to have to make the assumption that $n$ cannot be a number that is in the set of all whole numbers$$n\in\mathbb{W}$$since not all real numbers are divisible.
2. For the duration of this question, I am going to assume that $n\neq0$ since it would probably be easier to prove if we used $0$ as an example (since $\frac{0}{1897}\text{ is just }0$), so$$n\in\mathbb{W}\text{ where }n\gt0$$

Set up a table $x, y, z$, where $x$ is the number that we are going to plug in for $n$, $y$ is the output, and $z$ is the number that we get when we divide the output by $1897$.

| $x$ | $y$ | $z$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $1$ | $1897$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $7635425$ | $4025$ |
| $3$ | $23864868937$ | $12580321$ |

See? Everything's going well at this point! Now, what happens when we plug in $x=4$?$$2903^4-803^4-464^4+261^4=70563731909825$$That doesn't look to bad, besides it being a bit of a large number! Now lets see what happens when we divide it by $1897$!$$\frac{70563731909825}{1897}\approx3.719753922\cdot10^{10}$$[image]$$\color{white}{.}$$Also doesn't look too bad, however, just to make sure, I'll multiply the denominator by $10^{10}$ to see if it actually is $3.7197539225×10^{10}$ exactly.$$\frac{70563731909825}{1987\cdot10^{10}}\approx3.55126984951$$$$\therefore\text{ for any }n\text{ where }n\in\mathbb{W}\text{ and }n\gt0$$$$2903^n-803^n-464^n+261^n\text{ is divisible by 1897 for }0\lt n\leq3$$

##### **My question**

---

Did I do something wrong, and if I did, what could I do to prove/disprove it more easily? I am not that great at proof by induction (i.e. I don't really understand it), so it might not be able to help me a whole lot.

Comment: Note that $1897=7\cdot 271$. Use little Fermat, i.e., $a^7\equiv a \bmod 7$, to show that it is divisibly by $7$, and similarly also by $271$.

Comment: For $n=4$, the expression is indeed divisible by $1897$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282903%5E4%E2%88%92803%5E4%E2%88%92464%5E4%2B261%5E4%29%2F1897

Comment: @Levent Oh okay I must've messed up with my math somewhere then.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843751/242) in the linked dupe explains the innate *symmetry* that enables great simplifications in these types of problems.

Comment: As mentioned, your arithmetic is incorrect for the $n=4$ case. Nor can you prove it for all $n$ brute force checking every case. It's best for site health to delete questions based on arithmetic errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1897 = 7 \times 271$ and $2903^{n} - 803^{n} - 464^{n} + 261^{n} \equiv_{7} 5^{n} - 5^{n} - 2^{n} + 2^{n} \equiv_{7} 0$ and $2903^{n} - 803^{n} - 464^{n} + 261^{n} \equiv_{271} 193^{n} - 261^{n} - 193^{n} + 261^{n} \equiv_{271} 0$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).